# Transfer likes from one page to another

Tags: facebook

Is there any process on Facebook to transfer page `likes` to another page?

Comment: Good question, I've wondered the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you go to this site: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

You can find a link to your webpage's fanpage, if you click on your website app.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to migrate fans in this way

Comment: Is there any way to connect a webpage to a fb page so that new likes for the webpage goes to fb page? In fb debugger (old ulr linter) I can see fb has assigned a graph id to my website which I think I should make it same as page id.

Comment: Point the like button at the page's URL - `<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/thingy/[PAGE ID]/>`

Comment: Oh thanks! Fastest answer ever I have got on web! :)